# Client computer cannot connect to the database of the c# .net application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, client

I connected my database as a (sql server database file) to mt c# .net application.
the connection string was given as a relative path. the client computer asks for sql express server, what should i do? which application should i install in the client pc?

Comment: Show us your local relative path.

Comment: "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\""+Application.StartupPath+"\\defects.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

Comment: @harshani: please don't post stuff like connection strings into comments - this is **very hard** to read.... instead: update your original question by editing it and nicely format your connection string!

Comment: Why didn't you attach the database in the normal way instead of using attchdbfilename?

Comment: sorry guys.....when you attach the database file in the normal way the connectionstring is developed automatically, so the the db path is given locally, when the software is installed it gives another error as "cannot find c:/user/harshani.......db" ,when i gave the above connection string that error didnt come up but asks for SQLEXPRESS on the machine. hope u can understand

Comment: even after i installed the sql express , the same error comes up

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the correct connection string, with the database server name.

If the application is supposed to connect to a local database (on the same machine as the application), you need to install SQL Express and setup the database on the client machine.